# Swift: How to add a backgroundView to a table cell, that does not get dragged?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift

I want to have a second contentView or a subView behind a UITableViewCell, that doesn't get dragged with the cell. Basically I want a UIButton to sit behind the cell and show up when it's dragged. I am trying to rebuild the action button scheme for right-swipes, because the built in one only supports left-swipes.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you looked for some ready solution like [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) at the GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

If a background image doesn't move with the tell then it's not part of the cell, it's part of the table view itself. I suggest you install a background image for the whole table view that's composited from images for each cell. You'll have to rebuild the image each time the user rotates his device however.